# obj/release folder constantly duplicating

Tags: c#, bots, publish, filepath, directory

Each time I publish my bot application to Azure, I get a new loop of folders within obj/release/package/packagetmp and it just repeats every time until eventually the folder says "Filepath exceeds maximum length" then I have to delete the release package to fix it.

How can I stop this from occuring?